# How to add validation to specific items in an array that are being rendered to the page using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am working in Vue JS (using the Vuetify framework) to create a form:

```
    <v-text-field 
        v-for="items in itemsArray"
        :key="items.id"
        v-model="items.data"
        :label="items.name"
    ></v-text-field>
```

This is what the itemsArray looks like:

```
    data: () => ({
        itemsArray: [
            {id: 6, name: 'Name'},
            {id: 1, name: 'Email'},
            {id: 17, name: 'Age'},
            {id: 3, name: 'Height'},
            {id: 4, name: 'Contact Number'},
        ],
    }),
```

How can I add validation to specific items in the array? For example, I want it so that the item with id: 4 and name 'Contact Number' has a maximum of 8 characters and those characters can only be numbers.

I've checked the Vuetify docs however it doesn't explain how you can validate when the items are being rendered to the page using a for loop

Comment: Apologies it was a spelling mistake on my part. It works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add validation rules to the item that you want to validate it as follows :

```
 itemsArray: [
            {id: 6, name: 'Name'},
            {id: 1, name: 'Email'},
            {id: 17, name: 'Age'},
            {id: 3, name: 'Height'},
            {id: 4, name: 'Contact Number',rules:{required: value => !!value || 'Required.', counter: value => value.length <= 8 || 'Max 8 characters'}},
        ]
```

and in template :

```
  <v-text-field 
        v-for="items in itemsArray"
        :key="items.id"
        v-model="items.data"
        :label="items.name"
```

**`:rules='items.rules?Object.values(items.rules):[]'`**

```
    ></v-text-field>
```

please check this [pen](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/XWbJJNv?editors=0011)